# flash activate internet explorer

Tags: javascript, flash

as you all know that if we use flash object in web page in internet explorer

Internet Explorer displays a box around Flash content and show a tooltip telling the user to click to activate the content.

i am using fixit it work fine but problem is once page loaded completely.

this object load it again.

any other solution...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u try

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

use it.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: i use this also, but i am using flash with transparent background, i did't find any help how to use this with transparent background...

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the Flash movie using SWFobject or any other javascript method out there.